# How to use a Web font with more than 65,535 glyphs

Tags: web-fonts, monospace

SVG font seems to be the right choice here because it uses XML. However it has been deprecated everywhere.
So is there an alternative *(or an alternative format)* for representing a long text which use ~70,000 glyphs. *(the current font I’m interested in is currently in the ps format and installed on my system)*.

Or is it possible to make a single font family for storing multiple range of glyphs?
Please note there are other limitations that answers to this question might solve.

Comment: SVG hasnt been deprecated. It has ever been more used than today. Maybe you mean Flash?

Comment: @joojaa : Yes, the format is not deprecated by the standard. However browsers are [removing support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-fonts).

Comment: Yes because they are moving to webtech. The biggest flaw of svg is too much of everything... Can yiu not use 2 separate webfonts?

Comment: @joojaa for a single text on the same page? How?

Comment: @user2284570 SVG is not being depreciated, only SVG text elements. Any way of having ~70,000 glyphs included will be a pain because of the load amount, load time, etc.

Comment: Yes, this needs to be made clear: support for SVG *fonts* is not the same as SVG support in general. The former is being replaces with webfonts (which is good). The latter is still completely supported. As for your question, is it the font that has that many glyphs? Is the content you are showing actually require that many?

Comment: @ZachSaucier I'd be very surprised to learn that SVG `<text>` elements are deprecated. I assume there's a misunderstanding.

Comment: @ThomasW. Sorry, I mispoke. SVG fonts are being depreciated, not the text element itself

Comment: @ZachSaucier Not with http static compression.

Comment: @DA01 : required by the page contents.

Answer (score 3):

I have not tried this myself, but you should be able to use two (or more) fonts, one that contained part of the glyphs, and another one with the rest.

So say you have FontA which has characters 1-30,000, and FontB, which has 30,001 to 70,000

You specify in your css a font stack:

```
body{
font-family: FontA, FontB, sans-serif;
}
```

And if a character is not found in FontA it will be set in FontB
([source](http://somadesign.ca/2009/subsetted-fallbacks-fonts/))

You can be even more specific and use the [unicode-range](https://24ways.org/2011/creating-custom-font-stacks-with-unicode-range/) css property to define what characters should come from which font.

Comment: Tried! some browsers like Opera or Chrome substitute characters from other font before using the next one. As the monospace factor is important the schema became far less readable. So this technique worth something but the fallback font should use the same family than the first one.